# showing that a complex number is a square root to another complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

i have this question in calculus which i don't understand fully. My teacher is not replying and i have around 3 hours to solve this, so i'm gonna ask here and hope for someone to help me.

the exercises says: let $d = -3+4i.$

show that the number $u = 1+2i$ is the square root for d, $(u^2=d)$

i do not really understand what the problem is, could someone please explain? no need to give me the answer right away, but to explain the problem here.

Comment: Just compute $u^2$ and compare with $d$.

Comment: i can't be more stupid... thanks for the answer

Comment: It is more correct to say that $u$ is a square root of $d$.  There is another one, $-1-2i$